# За что отвечает метод setUndecorated(false)?

Tags: java, swing

За что отвечает метод `setUndecorated(false)`?

Comment: Чтобы закрыть вопрос, поставьте галку напротив правильного ответа.

Answer (score 2):

С помощью метода

```
public void setUndecorated(boolean undecorated)
```

класса `Frame` можно управлять *внешним видом* самого `Frame`. Под *внешним видом* здесь подразумеваются заголовок, рамка и кнопки в правом верхнем углу окна.

При вызове данного метода с флагом `true` – приведенные выше элементы не будут отображены, при вызове с флагом `false` – получите дефолтное отображения окна (со всеми этими элементами).

Comment: Огромное спасибо